# Cursor insert to identical rows instead of one

Tags: t-sql, insert, cursor, duplicates

I'm trying to handle some active requests using Cursor:

```
DECLARE @ID bigint --id attachments
DECLARE @personID BIGINT
DECLARE @territoryServiceID BIGINT
DECLARE @isAtClosed BIT

DECLARE @currentServerDate DATETIME = '2016-01-01 01:10:00.000' --this change GETDATE()
DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME SET @BeginDate = @currentServerDate
DECLARE @periodYear INT SET @periodYear = DATEPART(YEAR,@currentServerDate) - 1

DECLARE cur cursor LOCAL STATIC
FOR
SELECT at.id, at.personID, at.territoryServiceID, ts.isClosing
FROM Attachments at
INNER JOIN Person p ON p.id = at.personID AND p.parentID IS NULL
INNER JOIN TerritoryServices ts ON ts.id = at.territoryServiceID
LEFT JOIN Attachments at2 ON at2.personID = at.personID AND at2.parentID = at.id AND at2.attachmentStatusID IN (2,11,12)
WHERE at.attachmentStatusID = 1 AND at.causeOfAttachID = 8 AND at.endDate IS NOT NULL
AND at2.id IS NULL
AND p.id IN (15300000019296419,15300000018501113,15300000014988209,414674754,420940229,409531785)


OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @personID, @territoryServiceID, @isAtClosed
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
DECLARE @personID_NVARCHAR NVARCHAR(MAX) SET @personID_NVARCHAR = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@personID)
PRINT '1 ('+@personID_NVARCHAR+')'

IF (@isAtClosed = 1) -- if ter of CA is closing
    BEGIN
        -- Insert error into ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach
        DECLARE @ErrorDescr NVARCHAR(MAX) SET @ErrorDescr = 'TerId: ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@territoryServiceID)
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach] ([AttachmentsID],[personID],[territoryServiceID],[periodYear],[reasonError],[addDate],[description])
        VALUES (@ID, @personID, @territoryServiceID, @periodYear, 1, GETDATE(), @ErrorDescr)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @terAt2ID BIGINT
        DECLARE @isAt2Close BIT = 0
        SELECT @isAt2Close = ts.isClosing, @terAt2ID = ts.id FROM Attachments at 
        INNER JOIN TerritoryServices ts ON ts.id = at.territoryServiceID
        WHERE at.personID = @personID AND at.attachmentStatusID = 2 AND at.endDate IS NULL

        IF (@isAt2Close = 1) -- if ter of attach is closing
            BEGIN 
                -- Insert error into ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach
                DECLARE @ErrorDescr2 NVARCHAR(MAX) SET @ErrorDescr2 = 'TerAttachId: ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@terAt2ID)
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach] ([AttachmentsID],[personID],[territoryServiceID],[periodYear],[reasonError],[addDate],[description])
                VALUES (@ID, @personID, @territoryServiceID, @periodYear, 2, GETDATE(), @ErrorDescr2)
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN 
                BEGIN TRY
                BEGIN TRANSACTION TranName
                    -- Search active request
                    DECLARE @ID_zapros BIGINT 
                    SELECT @ID_zapros = id FROM Attachments WHERE personID = @personID AND endDate IS NULL AND attachmentStatusID != 2 AND id != @ID
                    IF (@ID_zapros IS NOT NULL) 
                        BEGIN
                            -- Canseled request

                            -- Block #1
                            -- Create cancel for active request
                            INSERT INTO Attachments (personID,orgHealthCareID,personAddressesID,territoryServiceID,attachmentProfileID,doctorID,
                                causeOfAttachID,careAtHome,senderRequestID,senderSystemID,attachmentStatusID,beginDate,endDate,parentID,userID,registratorID,
                                actualAttachmentID,ConflictAttachment,Node,regDate,isMigrated,isDuplicate,oldPersonID,servApplicationID,Num)
                            SELECT at.personID,at.orgHealthCareID,at.personAddressesID,at.territoryServiceID,at.attachmentProfileID, at.doctorID,
                                8,at.careAtHome,NULL,NULL, 11, @BeginDate, @BeginDate, at.id, 
                                at.userID, at.registratorID, at.actualAttachmentID, NULL,NULL,at.regDate,NULL,0,at.oldPersonID,NULL,at.Num
                            FROM Attachments at 
                            WHERE at.id = @ID_zapros

                            -- Set endDate for active request
                            UPDATE Attachments SET endDate = @BeginDate WHERE id = @ID_zapros
                        END

                    --Search active attach
                    DECLARE @ID_prikrep BIGINT
                    SELECT @ID_prikrep = id FROM Attachments WHERE personID = @personID AND endDate IS NULL AND attachmentStatusID = 2
                    IF (@ID_prikrep IS NOT NULL) 
                        BEGIN
                            -- Block #2
                            -- Insert detach
                            INSERT INTO Attachments (personID,orgHealthCareID,personAddressesID,territoryServiceID,attachmentProfileID,doctorID,
                                causeOfAttachID,careAtHome,senderRequestID,senderSystemID,attachmentStatusID,beginDate,endDate,parentID,userID,registratorID,
                                actualAttachmentID,ConflictAttachment,Node,regDate,isMigrated,isDuplicate,oldPersonID,servApplicationID,Num)
                            SELECT at.personID,at.orgHealthCareID,at.personAddressesID,at.territoryServiceID,at.attachmentProfileID, at.doctorID,
                                8,at.careAtHome,NULL,NULL, 8, @BeginDate, @BeginDate, at.id, 
                                at.userID, at.registratorID, at.actualAttachmentID, NULL,NULL,at.regDate,NULL,0,at.oldPersonID,NULL,at.Num
                            FROM Attachments at 
                            WHERE at.id = @ID_prikrep

                            --Set endDate for active attach
                            UPDATE Attachments SET endDate = @BeginDate WHERE id = @ID_prikrep
                        END

                    -- Attach CA
                    INSERT INTO Attachments (personID,orgHealthCareID,personAddressesID,territoryServiceID,attachmentProfileID,doctorID,
                        causeOfAttachID,careAtHome,senderRequestID,senderSystemID,attachmentStatusID,beginDate,endDate,parentID,userID,registratorID,
                        actualAttachmentID,ConflictAttachment,Node,regDate,isMigrated,isDuplicate,oldPersonID,servApplicationID,Num)
                    SELECT at.personID,at.orgHealthCareID,at.personAddressesID,at.territoryServiceID,at.attachmentProfileID, at.doctorID,
                        8,at.careAtHome,NULL,NULL, 2, @BeginDate, NULL, at.id, 
                        at.userID, at.registratorID, at.actualAttachmentID, NULL,NULL,at.regDate,NULL,0,at.oldPersonID,NULL,at.Num
                    FROM Attachments at 
                    WHERE at.id = @ID

                COMMIT TRANSACTION TranName

                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TranName

                    -- Insert error into ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach
                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ErrorHandlingCampainOfAttach] ([AttachmentsID],[personID],[territoryServiceID],[periodYear],[reasonError],[addDate],[description])
                    VALUES (@ID, @personID, @territoryServiceID, @periodYear, 3, GETDATE(),ERROR_MESSAGE())
                END CATCH
            END
    END

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @personID, @territoryServiceID, @isAtClosed
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

But sometimes the result is inserted into two rows instead of one, in block statement "Create cancel for active request" (Block #1) or "Insert detach" (Block #2). Each run on the same recording is done in different ways, sometimes OK, sometimes duplicated entry in the block #1, block #2 times. For some reason, one of the inserts is performed twice, but not always.

Please tell me what is the reason for this behavior

Comment: could it be that there  are two Attachment records with the same ID? Try using a DISTINCT to see if that is the case?

Comment: No, this can not be, the query returns exactly 6 records. ID's are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out pretty simple:

```
DECLARE @ID_zapros BIGINT
SELECT @ID_zapros = id FROM Attachments WHERE personID = @personID AND endDate IS NULL AND attachmentStatusID != 2 AND id != @ID
```

When this query returns NULL is written into the variable the previous value and not NULL. The solution to this problem reset the variable after insert statement or before set:

```
DECLARE @ID_zapros BIGINT
SELECT @ID_zapros = id FROM Attachments WHERE personID = @personID AND endDate IS NULL AND attachmentStatusID != 2 AND id != @ID

IF (@ID_zapros IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Attachments (personID,orgHealthCareID,personAddressesID,territoryServiceID,attachmentProfileID,doctorID,
                                causeOfAttachID,careAtHome,senderRequestID,senderSystemID,attachmentStatusID,beginDate,endDate,parentID,userID,registratorID,
                                actualAttachmentID,ConflictAttachment,Node,regDate,isMigrated,isDuplicate,oldPersonID,servApplicationID,Num)
        SELECT at.personID,at.orgHealthCareID,at.personAddressesID,at.territoryServiceID,at.attachmentProfileID, at.doctorID,
                                8,at.careAtHome,NULL,NULL, 11, @BeginDate, @BeginDate, at.id, 
                                at.userID, at.registratorID, at.actualAttachmentID, NULL,@nvar_ID,at.regDate,NULL,0,at.oldPersonID,NULL,at.Num
        FROM Attachments at 
        WHERE at.id = @ID_zapros


        UPDATE Attachments SET endDate = @BeginDate WHERE id = @ID_zapros

        SET @ID_zapros = NULL

    END
```

... or

```
DECLARE @ID_zapros BIGINT
SET @ID_zapros = NULL

SELECT @ID_zapros = id FROM Attachments WHERE personID = @personID AND endDate IS NULL AND attachmentStatusID != 2 AND id != @ID

IF (@ID_zapros IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Attachments (personID,orgHealthCareID,personAddressesID,territoryServiceID,attachmentProfileID,doctorID,
                                causeOfAttachID,careAtHome,senderRequestID,senderSystemID,attachmentStatusID,beginDate,endDate,parentID,userID,registratorID,
                                actualAttachmentID,ConflictAttachment,Node,regDate,isMigrated,isDuplicate,oldPersonID,servApplicationID,Num)
        SELECT at.personID,at.orgHealthCareID,at.personAddressesID,at.territoryServiceID,at.attachmentProfileID, at.doctorID,
                                8,at.careAtHome,NULL,NULL, 11, @BeginDate, @BeginDate, at.id, 
                                at.userID, at.registratorID, at.actualAttachmentID, NULL,@nvar_ID,at.regDate,NULL,0,at.oldPersonID,NULL,at.Num
        FROM Attachments at 
        WHERE at.id = @ID_zapros


        UPDATE Attachments SET endDate = @BeginDate WHERE id = @ID_zapros

    END
```